# Teradata rename table if exists

Tags: rename, teradata, exists

I'm using Teradata. I'd like rename a table with a script sql and not using bteq, if a specific conditions is satisfied.

In particular:

if TABLE_A exists => rename table TABLE_B to TABLE_B_OLD

In Sql Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE_A', 'U') IS NULL
 EXEC sp_rename 'TABLE_B', 'TABLE_B_OLD';
```

In Oracle:

```
DECLARE
        cnt NUMBER;
        BEGIN 
            select COUNT(*) INTO cnt from sys.user_tables where table_name = 'TABLE_A'

            IF cnt>0 THEN
                execute immediate 'rename table TABLE_B to TABLE_B_OLD';
            END IF;
        END;
```

How can I made it with Teradata,

Thanks

Fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on a relatively modern version of Teradata, you can do this in SQL Assistant (or BTEQ):

```
select
count (*)
from
dbc.tablesv where tablename = '<your table>'
and databasename = '<your db>'
having count (*) > 0;

.if activitycount = 1  then .GOTO RenameTable;
.if activitycount <> 1  then .quit;

.LABEL RenameTable

rename table <your table> <your new name;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've a modern version: 14. I tried your script in SQL Assistant and it works. If i run it on Teradata Studio or on a environment without use BTEQ it doesn't work for syntax error. According to you, is there an other solution?

Comment: Well, that is BTEQ syntax, I don't think Teradata Studio supports it.  I don't know of any other way to do it without SA or BTEQ.  Is there any reason you can't use one of those two?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE IF_EXISTS_RENAME
(
IN table_name VARCHAR(30),
IN new_table_name VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbc.tables WHERE 1=1 AND tablename = table_name and databasename=DATABASE) THEN
  CALL DBC.SysExecSQL('RENAME TABLE ' || table_name ||' to '|| new_table_name);
END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed code provided by @access_granted to include Database Name as variable

```sql
REPLACE PROCEDURE FAR.RENAME_TABLE 
(
IN table_name VARCHAR(30),
IN new_table_name VARCHAR(30),
IN db_name VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    declare my_sql VARCHAR(1000);

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM dbc.tables 
             WHERE 1=1 AND tablename = table_name and databasename= db_name) 
    THEN
        set my_sql ='RENAME TABLE ' || table_name ||' to '||      new_table_name||';' ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql;
    END IF;

END;
```

Calling the procedure with three arguments:

1. Old Table Name
2. New Table Name
3. Database Name

`call FAR.RENAME_TABLE('TEST_ABC','TEST_11','FAR')`